# Is there a Tensorflow function for finding the indices next to a condition?

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing

I have a sparse tensor of indiscriminate size, with some non-zero entries. I can use tf.where(tensor != 0) to obtain the index of the location of the non-zero entry. For my application, it would be useful to get the index of the location of the non-zero entry *and* the indices on either side of the location of the non-zero entry. Is there a clever way I can do this with indexing or with some sort of built-in function?

For example, if I have
`x = tf.constant([0,0,1,0,0])`, then `tf.where(x != 0)` would return `tf.Tensor([[2]], shape = [1,1], dtype = int64)`. However, the function I have in mind would have some sort of method of instead returning `tf.Tensor([[1][2][3]], shape = [3,1], dtype = int64)`

The closest thing to a solution I could come up with was this for loop

```
x = tf.constant([0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.])

index = tf.where(x != 0)
next_to = tf.zeros(shape = [0,1], dtype = tf.int64)
for i in index[0]:
  index_minus_one = index - 1
  index_naught = index
  index_plus_one = index + 1

  next_to = tf.concat([next_to, index_minus_one, index_naught, index_plus_one], axis = 0)

print(next_to)
```

which gives the output  `tf.Tensor([[13][14][15]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=int64)`. However,  this ends up interleaving the returned indices if there is more than one non-zero element, which is something I would like to be able to handle. Surely there's a built-in function that I haven't heard of that I could use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def f(x):                                                                                                                                                                   
    a = tf.tile(x, [3])                                                                                                                                                     
    b = tf.constant([1, 0, -1], shape=[3, 1], dtype=tf.int64)                                                                                                               
    sliced = tf.slice((a - b), begin=[0,0], size=[3,1])                                                                                                                     
    return tf.reshape(sliced, shape=[3, 1])                                                                                                                                 
output = tf.map_fn(f, index)
```